# ngRepeat filtered result to another page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm getting some posts to my ionic app via JSON data , and I'm filetering the posts receipts with a searchbar input , the problem that the search bar input and the filetered results are showing in the same page , I want to show the result in another page , and the first page will be only for the search bar .
(I added the new page and I'll add a button for the search page 
)
This is my code :

```
<label class="item item-input">
<input type="text" placeholder="Nom du Jneyne" ng-model="nom" ng-
change="showSelectValue(nom)">
</label>

<ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap item-icon-right" 
ng-repeat="post in (filteredItems = ( recent_posts 
| filter:{title:nom} " href="#/main/postDetail/{{post.id}}">


<img ng-src="{{post.thumbnail}}" />
<h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
<p ng-bind-html="post.excerpt" </p>

<ion-option-button class="button-dark">
<i class="icon ion-heart"></i>
</ion-option-button>

</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: so the two pages have two controllers or one

Comment: the same controller for the two pages

Comment: i think you can only hide the rest that you don't want and toggle between search and data in the same page

Comment: how can I toggle in the same page ?

Comment: make ng-hide and ng-show based on condition you make in the button click

Answer (score 0):

try adding `ng-if`  and change code as

```
<label class="item item-input" ng-if="srhItem">
<input type="text" placeholder="Nom du Jneyne" ng-model="nom" >
<input type ="submit" value="search" ng-click="showSelectValue(nom)"> 
</label>
```

and your display part to

```
<div ng-if = displayResult>
<ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap item-icon-right" 
ng-repeat="post in (filteredItems = ( recent_posts 
| filter:{title:nom} " href="#/main/postDetail/{{post.id}}">


<img ng-src="{{post.thumbnail}}" />
<h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
<p ng-bind-html="post.excerpt" </p>

<ion-option-button class="button-dark">
<i class="icon ion-heart"></i>
</ion-option-button>

</ion-item>
</div>
```

and add `$scope.srhItem = false`,`$scope.displayResult = true` in your `showSelectValue()` function.and dont forget to add `$scope.srhItem = true` at the beginning of your controller

Comment: thanks but the problem that I couldn't access to showSelectValue()

Comment: @MedAnis see my updated answer...i have changed `ng-change` to `ng-click`